# How to scrape data from website using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am try to scrape data but they will provide me an error this is website link https://www.dastelefonbuch.de/Suche/Zahnarzt

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
url='https://www.dastelefonbuch.de/Suche/Zahnarzt'
driver =webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(url)
vid=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='vcard']")
for item in vid:
    title=item.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='name']").text
    phone=item.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='nr']").text
    website=item.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='icon icon_url']").text
    print(title,phone,website)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you extract xpath on an item you have to change a bit xpath, saying lookup on current node with ".//"

Change

```
title=item.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='name']").text
```

to

```
title=item.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='name']").text
```

Checkout and feedback if it works

Comment: it give me the correct but why put `dot` can you tell me

Comment: is cause // means global (all html), and .// means from the node (web element, your div). Also just one / means direct  childrens. Here  you can get more info about it and more complexity Xpaths https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `vid=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='vcard']")` which returns a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) you need `vid=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='vcard']")` which would return a list to iterate as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

vid = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='vcard']")
for item in vid:
    title=item.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='name']").text
    phone=item.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='nr']").text
    website=item.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='icon icon_url']").text
    print(title,phone,website)
```

Comment: they give these error `NameError: name 'find_elements_by_xpath' is not defined`

Comment: Checkout the answer update and let me know the status

Comment: they give us wong  output repeatedly print `one name` many time

Comment: and also not provide website link

Comment: @AmenAziz This answer was based on `find_element_by_xpath()` and `find_elements_by_xpath()` stuff, which I strongly believe have got you started in the right direction. _`repeatedly print one name`_ sounds like a different issue all together and you may like to raise a new question.